# How to stop Cassandra on windows at Port 9160

Tags: windows, cassandra, apigee, usergrid

How to stop Cassandra on windows at Port 9160

```
S:\apigeeUserGrid>a127 usergrid start [Error: Port 9160 in use. Stop Cassandra process (or other process using port) and try again.]
```

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra is still running. You should be able to stop it with a127 usergrid stop then restart. If its hanging around too much longer can stop it with tasklist/taskkill, wait a little bit and try again.